# Is asking about search engines ( startpage.com + duckduckgo.com) On Topic on superuser?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I have a question that relates to a computer , web application, in particular it is the search engine **startpage.com**.

My question is basically: "Is there a way to query search results without all the bloated and repeated JS and unnecessary markup?"

I would like to ask in this META question is something like this would be a question in line with the field of superuser.com

Answer (score 6):

No.

Webapps and websites are off-topic here as stated by the [help](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

> **not about** …
>
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress

For Web Applications there is [WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)